# modular exponentiation for summation series

Tags: c++, recursion, modular-arithmetic

I am working on a project for school and I have run into a problem. Our goal is to calculate the last six decimal digits of the series of sums, `n, i = 0, i^i` using modular arithmetic. I have found a recursive method online to help me better understand how modular exponentiation works.

```
int exponentMod(int A, int B, int C)
{
    // Base cases
    if (A == 0)
        return 0;
    if (B == 0)
        return 1;
 
    // If B is even
    long y;
    if (B % 2 == 0) {
        y = exponentMod(A, B / 2, C);
        y = (y * y) % C;
    }
 
    // If B is odd
    else {
        y = A % C;
        y = (y * exponentMod(A, B - 1, C) % C) % C;
    }
 
    return (int)((y + C) % C);
}
```

This method works fine when I am just calculating one exponent, however I'm not sure how to make this work for the problem I have been given with the series. The purpose of modular exponentiation is because we are working with large exponents, so I can not just add them up normally then mod by 1000000. I can't add up the numbers output by the above function either because they don't produce the full number that I need, when the numbers get larger, to get the correct summation. Can Someone point me in the right direction for finding the last six digits of the summation using modular arithmetic?

Comment: `the series of sums, n, i = 0, i^i` -- do you mean the sum from `i=0` to `i=n` of `i^i`? What are your constraints?

Comment: Are you sure about i^i ? That sounds rather strange . . .

Comment: You can add the results, just make sure to reduce the sum mod 1000000 often enough to prevent overflow